# ESLint complains if I assign a function parameter, but not if I run a function that changes the function parameter. Why?

Tags: javascript, eslint

The following code selects all div elements and changes their class to 'test. ESLint complains about assignment to property of function parameter:

```
  [...document.getElementsByTagName('div')].forEach(div => {
    div.className = 'test';
  });
```

However, if I mutate the parameter by running a function or method, then I get no complaints.
The following code does the exact same thing as the code that gets complained about, but is less efficient and less readable:

```
 [...document.getElementsByTagName('div')].forEach(div => {
    div.classList.remove(...div.classList);
    div.classList.add('test');
  });
```

Why is one okay but the other is not?

Comment: I expect the rule is as simple as "check for an equals sign". But the [documentation spells out why it might be a problem](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign)If you're happy with that code just turn off the rule. (Incidentally `forEach` is the only array method (iirc) that works on node collections without you having to convert it to an array first.)

Comment: Just use a `for (const div of document.getElementsByTagName('div')) { … }` loop instead :-)

Answer (score 0):

ESLint's [no-param-reassign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign) rule includes prohibiting assignment of function arguments' properties. But it has a `props` option that you could configure to `false` if you want to keep the rule more generally but also allow it to mutate function arguments without reassigning them.

As the documentation page explains, the rule exists because reassigning (or mutating) function arguments will also mutate the `arguments` object, which may be confusing.

There's no way for ESLint to know if an object's method is going to mutate that object, which is why it can't error when you call a method that mutates a function argument.

In my experience, this side effect of mutating `arguments` is pretty rarely an issue, especially when you're just mutating function arguments instead of reassigning them. What you're doing in this example clearly isn't going to cause the sort of issue this rule is meant to help with.

Personally, this is a rule that I turn off in my projects.

Comment: "*reassigning function parameters will also mutate the `arguments` object*" - it doesn't in strict mode, making this a weak argument

Comment: I agree. Like I said, I tend to turn this rule off in my own projects. But that's the explanation given by ESLint's documentation.